# Make POST JSON Request From HTML Script To A Node.JS App In Another Domain

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, node.js

I am trying to send string data via making a post json request by javascript inside an .erb.html file, to a node.js app in another domain, which uses express to handle incoming requests.

I read from several posts that such thing with XMLHttpRequest alone is not possible. How one sends such request to such an app?

Comment: This is possible, I just think you need to read something about CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
The server has to send some headers so that the cross-domain request is not blocked.

Comment: See for Header : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response header; If it is `*` then you can send Ajax Request to that domain; But if it is pointing to same domain; Then I'm afraid you can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with an XMLHttpRequest, the remote server would have to have CORS heaers configured.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a
>   resource from a different domain, protocol, or port to its own. For
>   example, an HTML page served from http://domain-a.com makes an 
>   src request for http://domain-b.com/image.jpg. Many pages on the web
>   today load resources like CSS stylesheets, images, and scripts from
>   separate domains.
>
> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and Fetch
>   follow the same-origin policy. So, a web application using
>   XMLHttpRequest or Fetch could only make HTTP requests to its own
>   domain. To improve web applications, developers asked browser vendors
>   to allow cross-domain requests.

Comment: Thank you. I will check on CORS and how to set it up with Node.Js then.