# CORS POST Request Returns Empty Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

As the later stage from this question " [Make POST JSON Request From HTML Script To A Node.JS App In Another Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629350/make-post-json-request-from-html-script-to-a-node-js-app-in-another-domain) ", I implemented a CORS POST request:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "parameter=test";
request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3009/param_upload', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {if (request.readyState==4) alert("It worked!");};
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send(params);
```

It is pretty much close to the examples in the internet. And this is my setup in my node.js server side:

```
app.use(cors());
var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ['*'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
```

Of course, my app.post function has cors(corsOptions) in its header. However somehow the body is empty. As request I got a very long response which doesn't have the test text inside. I might be missing a point but looked around and coulnd't find it. If anyone helps, I will be very glad.

Comment: Look for errors in the console? For `allowedHeaders` & `*` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored

Comment: The function returns successfully. There are no errors. I will check the allowedHeaders.

Comment: "However somehow the body is empty" empty on node JS side or in the sended http request itself ? And why do you create a corsOptions object after using cors middleware? you have to give those options to cors middleware function in order to be active : ```app.use(cors(corsOptions));```

Comment: I only saw the node.js side and it's empty there. An example suggested to use that corsOptions with cors() inside a function if that function only requires CORS, hence implemented in that way. Will try with your suggested way as well.

Comment: @Gatsbill Is there any way to check the sent form in web script side?

Comment: you can use your browser inspector. Right click and inspect most of the time. And then go to the Network tab. Now you can see all request, and when you click on a request you should see the details of it.

Comment: @Gatsbill I checked from both inspector and wireshark. The params are sent by the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to use BodyParser middleware.

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

With this middleware all your body data will be in req.body.

Exemple:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    // body data
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot this. Thank you SO much. I have the json one for other requests but forgot to check if I needed one for urlencoded strings. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: I am having same error it is not resolving with answer